# How to enable network sharing (Windows XP) on a removable drive when it is plugged in?

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, network-shares

When a removable USB HDD is plugged into a Windows XP machine, can I make Windows XP share it automatically? The drive is moved around quite often, and it is a hassle having to 'reshare' it each time it is plugged in. I was looking at the mountvol command, which might do what I want, but I don't want to waste time and effort if there is an existing solution.

Currently I use

```
mountvol c:\extern \\?\Volume{ volume_id }
```

in a .bat file in the root of the drive, with c:\extern shared, but I'd like this to trigger whenever the drive is plugged in, without needing to enable AutoRun... unless AutoRun can be enable only for specific volumes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an autorun.inf in the root of the drive that calls a .bat that maps the drive via [net share](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490712.aspx). This seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: What drive letter do I map to the share? The drive letter assigned by the OS changes if other storage devices are plugged in. Can you map via volume id instead?